# Java - generate complex excel report

Tags: java, excel, reporting

I'm trying change the system of excel generation in a project. Actually, for every report there is an excel template saved on the db, but for every little change I must work for one day, moving all the cell and formulas manually. 
Unfortunately, is not a simple report like a normale table, is similar to a card with a lot of sub category. Here an example of the report: 
[image: Example]
Now, what's the best way to create this kind of report? I try with Jasper, but there's some memory problem and seems not so easy to create. The best way is to pass to the  report a bean with all the informations.
Many thanks in advance to all of you.

Comment: @vels4j:  I had apache POI, and I use them for a simple report. If is possible, I need to use an excel template. IN this report there are hide columns, complex formulas and many boxes, and it would be nice designe a report with a tool that make the things easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you may use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), [JExcel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) e.t.c. You may create Excel files template and fill data into static template file. But nevertheless it is require a lot of work to creating report.

What problem with memory do you had with Jasper and don't have with POI? [Jasper](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) has great feature - [Virtualizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/virtualizer/index.html) which allow to build giant reports on the disk. Also [iReport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) is a very useful tool to build Excel templates. Also, you can create a type of report view in one line.

Comment: A colleague say that if I have some large reports, like 200 pages, Jasper create some memory problems and the application chrash, I trusted him..

Comment: Can you esstimate how big your report should be? Jasper use POI to generate Excel file, so it will not worse than POI. Also if you has a lot data you may use virtualization feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an excel template you can try JXLS. http://jxls.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Xylophone](https://github.com/CourseOrchestra/xylophone) is another alternative for complex XLS reports. It is built on top of Apache POI. It uses Excel report template files and XML data sources.